# remove description in views exposed filter

Tags: views

Is it possible to remove the description of views exposed filter widgets in other way as css display:none?

I tried to unset $widget->description, but without any success.

Comment: Leave the field blank?

Comment: It's a standard description. There's no field. Or I already didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done either via theme or custom module:

```
function MODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form['#id'] == 'FORM_NAME')
    {
        $form['#info']['filter-FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['label'] = '';
    }
}
```

use `dpm($form);` from the [Devel Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to get the complete form name, and field names for non-content type filter criteria:

A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers ...

> Devel Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins.
>   This module can print a summary of all database queries for each page
>   request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many
>   times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query
>   multiple times), and how long each query took (short is good - use
>   cache for complex queries). Also a dprint_r($array) function is
>   provided, which pretty prints arrays. Useful during development.
>   Similarly, a ddebug_backtrace() is offerred.

Be aware that removing the label (description) will change the layout of the filter itself, so some css might be required to fix things.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't mean the label. I meant the description. I did a var_dump($variables) and got the syntax to the description. I got success with if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-model-overview-page') {
    $form['term_node_tid_depth']['#description'] = '';
  }.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already an answer, that is very technical, as it is supposed to be on this site.

Base-level developers, who find hard to dig through a ton of information like Drupal's dump($variables), can fulfill the 'impossible' task of removing the description from an exposed filter via the Better Exposed Filters module.
https://www.drupal.org/node/766974

The module can tweak exposed filters in various ways. One is to override the description, so you may want to override the exposed filter's unwanted text with a blank space.

HTML in the override form gets interpreted, so you can enter the corresponding HTML entity. If a single blank space is still "too big", wrap it with a  and style it to 1x1 pixel size.